# Zoom functionality on PDF not working in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have recently started using viewer version 2.12.*, as I needed to move to this version for some of its new functionality.

However I now get the below error whenever I try to zoom in on PDF that is loaded in the viewer. I am able to zoom out, but not zoom in.

The zoom functionality works fine in version 2.10.

[image]

Comment: We're investigating this issue. Will update you once it's fixed. Please use an older version for now.

Comment: I have actually started using version 2.13.*, which so far works well.